# Can I express recursive relationships of generic types with type constraints in F#?

Tags: f#

Given the following type

```
type WorkflowStep<'next, 'prev, 'cancel> =
     abstract member Next : unit -> 'next
     abstract member Prev : unit -> 'prev
     abstract member Cancel : unit -> 'cancel
```

I'd like to express the fact that `'next`, `'prev` and `'cancel` should also be of type `WorkflowStep` or of type `unit` is this possible to encode on the type level with F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless your description is missing some details that would make it unfeasible, there's a rather straightforward encoding that doesn't even require the type to be generic:

```
type Transition =
    | Step of WorkflowStep
    | Done

 and WorkflowStep =
     abstract member Next : unit -> Transition
     abstract member Prev : unit -> Transition
     abstract member Cancel : unit -> Transition
```

where `Transition` captures your requirement for the `WorkflowStep` to either produce another step or a unit value. This gives you a sort of inverted, CPS-like mechanism for flow control.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. If this were to be implemented it would mean that workflow would itself contain an infinite sequence of generics which is sadly not supported in f#.

Here is a more detailed explanation of why using a simplified version of your workflow type provided above.

```
//error workflow must be provided a type
type Workflow<'t when 't :> Workflow<_>> = 
    abstract member Next : unit -> 't
```

However when we do specify a type parameter 
for the workflow that is returned it now requires 2 parameters to be applied.

```
//workflow now requires 2 parameters
type Workflow<'nextvalue, 't when t:>Workflow<'nextvalue>>
    abstract member Next : unit->'t
```

It is easy to see that in order to create a Workflow class we need an infinite number of generic arguments which f# does not support.

One alternative would be to specify that a your workflow type can only work on one workflow if so your resulting code would look something like this.

```
type Workflow<'value> = 
    abstract member Next : unit -> Workflow<'value> option
    abstract member Prev : unit -> Workflow<'value> option
    abstract member Cancel : unit -> Workflow<'value> option
```

The option type you see above is so that you can return either a value (Some) or unit (None)

Note this type of list of types does have a name and it is implemented in some language it is called a variadic type.